# Firebase Realtime Database - Structuring with relationships

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Guys need some input creating a data structure that can be scaled for my use case.

I as a user can have many followers & can follow others too. So when I create a post my followers should get it. The Typical use case similar to Twitter or FB, but not so complex.

So for Instance I(Joseph) follow 2 users, hence my feed should be populated with the posts from the users I follow.

[image: A Base structure defined as of now]

How can I fetch the posts of persons I follow. Or please guide on how to achieve the same using Firebase Realtime DB (NoSQL)

Answer (score 1):

```
{
 "following":{
    "josephid":{ 
       "name"  : "joseph"
       "naber" : true
       "roger" : true
 }
}
 "followposts":{
        "pushid":{
          "foriegnid": "pushid1"
          "foriegnfollowid": "josephid"
       }
       "anotherpushid":{
         "foriegnid": "pushid2"
         "foriegnfollowid": "josephid"
       }

 }
}
```

Create another node that will take the `ids` in the node `post` and the `id` of the current user. That way the people that person is following and the posts are connected with each other. The `Foriegnid` and `foriegnfollowid` is just a name not an id but the value is the pushids of the posts and the `userid`

Comment: Okay so now we have the id's. But doesn't require this querying each and every posts to get the data.

Comment: check this link https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/structuring-data.html#section-join @SharanMohandas

Comment: You can nest it, but this is a better option. The link above actually have doc for all three platform on how to join @SharanMohandas

Comment: Yeah, I was apprehensive about having multiple requests for each posts. But Firebase itself encourages it. Shall look at how this approach performs

Comment: @SharanMohandas yes i think this approach will work out, since its logical